# FirebaseRecyclerAdapterで画像を表示させたい

Tags: android, java

Firebaseのチャットのサンプルプログラムを利用し、勉強していますが、
チャット画面で画像の表示ができません。

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/index.html

・参考 web版 
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/index.html

`FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`で画像をセットしようとしています。

`viewHolder`に画像をセットしているのですが、画像のない`viewHolder`にも
画像が表示されてしまいます。

```
mFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<FriendlyMessage,
            MessageViewHolder>(
            FriendlyMessage.class,
            R.layout.item_message,
            MessageViewHolder.class,
            mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(MESSAGES_CHILD)) {


        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final MessageViewHolder viewHolder,
                                          final FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage, final int position) {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);


            viewHolder.messageTextView.setText(friendlyMessage.getText());
            viewHolder.messengerTextView.setText(friendlyMessage.getName());
            if (friendlyMessage.getPhotoUrl() == null) {
                viewHolder.messengerImageView
                        .setImageDrawable(ContextCompat
                                .getDrawable(MainActivity.this,
                                        R.drawable.ic_account_circle_black_36dp));
            } else {
                Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
                        .load(friendlyMessage.getPhotoUrl())
                        .into(viewHolder.messengerImageView);
            }

            if (friendlyMessage.getImageUrl() ！= null) {

                mFirebaseStorageReference = mFirebaseStorage.getReferenceFromUrl(friendlyMessage.getImageUrl());
                mFirebaseStorageReference.getMetadata().addOnSuccessListener( new OnSuccessListener<StorageMetadata>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess( StorageMetadata storageMetadata ) {

                        mDownloadUri = storageMetadata.getDownloadUrl();

                        Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
                                .load(mDownloadUri.toString())
                                .into(viewHolder.messageImageView);



                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                    }
                });
            }
```

画像のURLは、DBに入っていないため、`mDownloadUri = storageMetadata.getDownloadUrl();`でURLを取得しています。

ちなみに、
https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/file-metadata#get_file_metadata
にある

```
// Alternatively you can get the metadata with
StorageMetadata storageMetadata = forestRef.getMetadata().getResult();
```

では、metadataが取得できないため、`addOnSuccessListener`で取得しています。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RecyclerView` ではその名の通り `View` の再利用をすることでリストの様なUIを実現をします。

> 画像のないviewHolderにも画像が表示されてしまいます。

ということですが、画像のセットされた `viewHolder` の中の `itemView` が再利用されることで過去にセットされた画像がそのまま表示されていると思われます。

画像が無い場合には `setImageResouce(0)` で画像をクリアするなどすると良いと思います。

```
if (friendlyMessage.getImageUrl() ！= null) {
    mFirebaseStorageReference = mFirebaseStorage.getReferenceFromUrl(friendlyMessage.getImageUrl());
    mFirebaseStorageReference.getMetadata().addOnSuccessListener( new OnSuccessListener<StorageMetadata>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess( StorageMetadata storageMetadata ) {

            mDownloadUri = storageMetadata.getDownloadUrl();

            Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
                    .load(mDownloadUri.toString())
                    .into(viewHolder.messageImageView);



        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        }
    });
} else {
    viewHolder.messageImageView.setImageResource(0);
}
```